# Two different ways to write variance of OLS beta

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model

I know that for OLS, we can write $var(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2 (X^{T}X)^{-1}$. Then for a the last variable $p$, we have $var(\hat{\beta}_p) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\langle x_p, x_p \rangle}$.

However, we can also start by finding an orthogonal basis $Z$ for $X$ by using the Gram-Schmidt procedure. Then we can write $X = ZR$ for some matrix $R$. You can show that $\hat{\beta}_p = \frac{\langle y, z_p \rangle}{\langle z_p, z_p \rangle}$. Rewrite $\langle y, z_p \rangle$ as $z_p^Ty$, use the properties of variance, and we get $var(\hat{\beta}_p) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\langle z_p, z_p \rangle}$. (Elements of Statistical Learning equation 3.28 and 3.29)

This means that $x_p$ is the same length as $z_p$. This doesn't make sense because $z_p$ is the orthogonal complement of the projection of $x_p$ onto the space spanned by $x_1$ through $x_{p-1}$. Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: What you assert  at the outset for the last variable is not correct.  It seems to suppose that the $(p,p)$ entry in the inverse of a matrix is the reciprocal of the $(p,p)$ entry in the matrix, but that is not generally true--and might even be a terrible approximation.

Comment: @whuber that makes sense appreciate the help